# What is a Cube in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I often hear comments like: "we need to get the data from the cube". A quick Google search shows way to create a cube, but no definition of what a cube is.

What my coworkers means with "extract the data from the cube"? A "cube" is just a specific structure of tables?

What in the world is a "cube" in SQL Server?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+what+is+a+cube&oq=sql+what+is+a+cube&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l3.2311j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Maybe do more than a "quick" Google search?

Comment: @TabAlleman I didn't know that OLAP cubes were the same as just cubes. Thank you.

Comment: So you found how to create a cube, saw no definition, then stopped? "What is a sql cube" in Google!

Comment: Cube is a simple dataset can be one table or combination of tables

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question.  But if you can imagine a simple data set, perhaps with census data.  The data you care about is number of residents in the US.

Now, we can subdivide that number into states, list each state on a row, and show the respective count for each state.  That's one 'dimension' on the data.

We could further interrogate this set by ethnicity.  We'd list ethnicities in columns, changing the table into a crosstab, and the count of residents for each ethnicity/state would be listed in the intersection of the corresponding column and row.

Finally, if we wanted a third dimension, maybe religion, we'd need some third direction (not rows or columns) to list these categories.  Our crosstab would become... a cube.

'Cube' is the shorthand name for a kind of database that has been specifically built to handle the various efficiency issues that come with analyzing datasets on many different dimensions -- slicing and aggregating those measures of data across the several available characteristics.

For Microsoft, the tool that generates Cubes is call SSAS - sql server analysis services.

Going into more detail would take hours and hours.  You will need to find some kind of tutorial resources and expect to make quite an investment of time if you want to learn the strengths and weaknesses of the various types of cubes and how to get information from them.

Answer (score 0):

Cube is a Dataset which could be result of one table (or) joined query on multiple tables. Cube has populated data and could be fetched real time as push.